# gnome shell doesn't read extensions

Tags: panel, gnome

I tried installing extensions through gnome tweak tool, manually through the .local/share directory and also through ppa when I can but still can't see the extension on the panel. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the version of Gnome Shell set for the extension. In metadata.json file in the folder of the extension, find "shell-version". It's one of the most common reason extensions won't work. To get version of Gnome Shell, "gnome-shell --version" in terminal.
Try installing the looking glass extension to find the error message if the above didn't work.

Comment: Hi! indeed now the extensions work in that I see them in gnome tweak tool (upgrade them to gnome 3.2), but now I they are switched to off and can't be moved. Thanks in advance