# Can't run GNOME Shell extensions - Gtk-CRITICAL errors in gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gtk, extension

I have GNOME Shell 3.2.1 installed on Ubuntu 11.10, and I'm trying to install extension on it. I downloaded via `apt-get` `dock` and `alternative-status-menu`, and ofcourse `gnome-tweak-tool`, but the extensions didn't appear in the tweak tool(after relogin).

So I followed the advice on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63987/gnome-shell-doesnt-read-extensions) and changed the versions in the metadata files, and than the extensions appeared in the tweak tool - but the tweak tool was printing many errors, and the extensions were not working - I didn't get the extra shutdown options in the status menu, and I didn't get the dock. I did notice a problem of not being able to click the leftmost area of the scrollbar when the dock extension was activated - like the dock was stealing the mouse pointer from the other applications - but still, no dock.

So, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73620/cant-use-gnome-shell-extensions-due-to-error-parsing-schema) and followed it to the letter, and it did get rid of the scheme parsing error, but I'm still getting alot of Gtk-CRITICAL errors when I run the tweak tool - I get 20 times the same error:
`(gnome-tweak-tool:3158): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed`
Also, now I can't enable the extensions in the tweak tool(before I edited the files in gtweak I could set them to `on` - they just didn't work) and I get an orange warning triangle next to them.

So, does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `gnome-tweak-tool` either from `git-master` or from the `ppa:ricotz/testing` PPA.
It has just been changed to fix compatibility with `gnome-shell` master.

Comment: Thanks. Now the teak tool works(had to reinstall the extensions though, since I messed with them manually).

Comment: Always a good idea to make a copy before playing :-) glad you got it wking :-)